# When using compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.4' I get the error below, but I am not using 26.0.0

Tags: android, android-support-library, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

When using `compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.4'` (the latest version of `com.google.android.support:wearable`) in my Wear app's build.gradle file, I get the error below, but I am not using 26.0.0.

What should I do? Even if I add compile 'com.android.support:wear:26.0.0' it still fails.

```
Error in the project's gradle file: 

Error:(22, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:wear:26.0.0
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:/.../wear/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many of the Wear elements (`BoxInsetLayout`, `WearableRecyclerView`, `SwipeDismissFrameLayout`, [full list here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/wear-ui-library.html#deprecations)) have been moved to the main android support library ([details](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-a1aPHO10g)). You can continue to use the old classes, but you probably want to use the latest stuff.

The build.gradle for your wear app includes compile `'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.4'` which uses some classes from `com.android.support:wear:26.0.0`. As called out in link above, they were moved from `com.google.android.support:wearable` to `com.android.support:wear`.

The support libraries (26) are now in Google's Maven repository (not downloaded via the support repository from the SDK Manager), so you need to add Google's Maven Repository your top level `build.gradle` file.

In `allprojects`, within `repositories`, add the code below. It goes under the `jcenter()` call.

For the Android Gradle plugin revision 2.3.3 with Gradle 3.3 (Android Studio 2.3.3), your code should look like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

For the Android Gradle plugin revision 3.0.0 (in alpha right now) with Gradle 4.1 (might be milestone version) in Android Studio 3.0.0, your code should look like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Comment: "For Android 2.3.3 and below"... You mean Gradle here?

Comment: Oops... meant Android Studio 2.3.3 and Android Studio 3.0.0.

Comment: It's actually Gradle that manages the `google()` repo, not the IDE

Comment: You're right, I should call that out. I added information about plugin and Gradle versions. I wanted to keep IDE versions since folks would be searching for that. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I just use the latest IntelliJ instead of Android Studio :)

Comment: Sorry for being a learner but where do I add the code mentioned? (In allprojects, within repositories, add the code below. It goes under the jcenter())

Comment: You want to add it in the your top level build.gradle file... within that file, you should see it structured in a way that you add it within allprojects then repositories... it should be clear once you look at the file.