# Android: Standard suggested dependencies give Gradle sync error. Failed to resolve: com.android.support:wear:24.0.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, wear-os

I'm developing a music application for both mobile & wear. I've completed building the base of the application on mobile, and now I want to start the wearable (2.0) part. I tried following the [tutorial on the Android Developer site](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html), but even following the base directions gives me a Gradle sync error. I tried adjusting the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion both to 24, which I use for my mobile gradle scrip. It didn't make a difference however.

This is the instruction mentioned:

```
In the build.gradle file for the Wear module:
>> In the android section, confirm that the compileSdkVersion is set to 25.

>> In the android section, confirm that the targetSdkVersion is set to 25.
Update the dependencies section as follows (requires the latest version of the Google Repository):  
compile 'com.android.support:wear:26.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.3'
provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.3'
```

[image: This is the error generated].

Clicking on "install repository and sync project" has no effect.

This is the build.gradle file for the Wear module.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "be.ehb.dt.finalwork_lievenluyckx_v001"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:wear:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.3'
    provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.3'
}
```

I'm really new to Android, and I don't really understand what is going wrong here. Any help is appreciated, even if it isn't a direct solution to the issue!

Comment: Your compileSDK is 24, it should be 25, the targetSDK as well and change `com.android.support:wear:24.0.0` to `com.android.support:wear:25.0.0` or 26

Comment: Like Chris Vera said? I tried it, but it gives the same error, with 25.0.0 or 26.0.0 instead of 24.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited: After trial-error,solution finally was found:

In **build.gradle**  file -> **allprojects**, within **repositories**,code below should be added...

1) For the Android Gradle plugin revision 2.3.3 with Gradle 3.3 (Android Studio 2.3.3)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

2) For the Android Gradle plugin revision 3.0.0 with Gradle 4.1(Android Studio 3.0.0)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

For more here: [When using compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.4' I get the error below, but I am not using 26.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45496409/when-using-compile-com-google-android-supportwearable2-0-4-i-get-the-error-b)

Comment: This gives the exact same error, but with 25.0.0 instead of 24.0.0

Comment: Bro you basically copied my answer, savage.

Comment: H.Brooks sorry man we put it simultaneously...!

Comment: Lieven Luyckx did you downloaded the repositories as instructions said?

Comment: Yeah all of them except the one in the current error. Clicking that link just does nothing at all.

Comment: go to SDK manager(next to ? symbol) and check in SDK Tools if Google Respository is checked...

Comment: It is checked, is that good or bad?

Comment: it's good!..check again all the repositories and change the dependencies...exactly what it says...then sync again!

Comment: everything looks okay... I'm really at a loss right now

Comment: check this might help you...:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45496409/when-using-compile-com-google-android-supportwearable2-0-4-i-get-the-error-b

Comment: Oh my god, thank you SO MUCH! Adding that forced some updates, which then forced me to upgrade my minSdkVersion. After that it just worked :D If you want your answer verified, feel free to repost it as an answer and ill verify it!

Comment: That's great to hear!Glad I helped!Best of luck with your app..I will just edit the post with the link and well verify it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your gradle to:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "be.ehb.dt.finalwork_lievenluyckx_v001"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:wear:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.3'
    provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.3'
}
```

Comment: It gives the same error, but with 26.0.0 instead of 24.0.0

Comment: On what are you testing or trying to run on?

Comment: HTC One M8 + One of the LG Urbanes, but I didnt run it once on the Wearable yet. I can't get past the gradle issue.

Comment: You'll need the new Google Maven repository for this to work